# determine power of number

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

i know  that if number is power of two,then it must satisfy (`x&(x-1))=0;` for example let's take `x=16 or 10000` `x-16=10000-1=01111` and (x&(x-1))=0;    for another non power number 7 for example, `7=0111`,`7-1=0110` `7&(7-1)=0110` which is not equal   0,my question how can i determine if   number is  some power of another number k? for example  625 is 5^4,and also how can i find in which power is equal k to n?i am interested using bitwise operators,sure i can find it by brute force methods(by standard algorithm,thanks a lot

Comment: Your question should probably be about "logarithm", not "power", of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary `k` there is only the generic solution:

```
bool is_pow(unsigned long x, unsigned int base) {
  assert(base >= 2);
  if (x == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  unsigned long t = x;
  while (t % base == 0) {
    t /= base;
  }
  return t == 1;
}
```

When `k` is a power of two, you can speed things up by checking whether `x` is a power of two and whether the number of trailing zero bits of `x` is divisible by `log2(k)`.

And if computational speed is important and your `k` is fixed, you can always use the trivial implementation:

```
bool is_pow5(unsigned long x) {
  if (x == 5 || x == 25 || x == 125 || x == 625)
    return true;
  if (x < 3125)
    return false;
  // you got the idea
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you're going to find a bitwise algorithm for determining that a number is a power of 5.

In general, given `y = n^x`, to find `x`, you need to use logarithms, i.e. `x = log_n(y)`.  Most languages don't offer a `log_n` function, but you can achieve it with the following identity:

```
log_n(y) = log(y) / log(n)
```

If `y` is an integer power of `n`, then `x` will be an integer.  Of course, due to the limitations of finite-precision computer arithmetic, you won't necessarily get the exact answer with the method above.

Comment: You can simply check n^((int)x) after determining of x, to be sure.

Comment: @Faust: Indeed.  Although you probably want to round rather than truncate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, you can't do that with just simple bit magic. Bits are typically good for powers of 2. For powers of, say, 5 you'd probably need to operate in base-5 system, where 1<sub>5</sub>=1<sub>10</sub>, 10<sub>5</sub>=5<sub>10</sub>, 100<sub>5</sub>=25<sub>10</sub>, 1000<sub>5</sub>=125<sub>10</sub>, 10000<sub>5</sub>=625<sub>10</sub>, etc. In base-5 system you can recognize powers of 5 just as easily as powers of 2 in binary. But you'd first need to convert your numbers to that base.